# Как подключить libxml в eclipse под linux

Tags: eclipse, c++, linux

В общем понадобилось мне подключить libxml2 к проекту в эклипсе.
В при мере написано сделать

```
#include <libxml/parser.h>
#include <libxml/tree.h>
```

пишет мне это **фатальная ошибка: libxml/parser.h: Нет такого файла или каталога**
Испробовал всю инфу что нашёл в сети на эту тему, ничего не момогло (в частности решение из этого обсуждения https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7584139/how-do-i-setup-libxml-in-eclipse-indigo-cdt-c)

Пробовал также добавить в список библиотек xml2 (насколько я знаю lib r нему автоматом приписывается) но тоже не помогло, хотя курл когда то подключал именно так.

Библиотека установлена, лежит в /usr/include/ но эклипс отказывается начисто её видеть, полный путь к файлам прописывать не хочу так как это неправильно.

Может кто ещё вариантов набросать что попробовать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У  вас в include path отсутствует каталог libxml с заголовочными файлами . Я не знаю как это делается конкретно в Eclipse, но в gcc надо просто добавить параметр -I$(PATH_TO_XML)

Comment: В общем покопавшись в настройках проекта нашёл параметр который влияет на значение -I$(PATH_TO_XML). Указал там путь до библиотеки (везде мне говорили что достаточно указать до директории с библиотеками а дальше эклипс сам будет искать, да и с курлом было всё намного проще). Спасибо.
Всё таки решение по ссылке верное, только в отличии от того решения путь нужно непосредственно до директории библиотеки указывать.

Comment: @Deadik: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, вы знаете, что делать.

Comment: @VladD Неужели харакири?!?

Comment: @VladD конечно знаю, нужно радоваться что помогли.

Comment: @alexlz: Ку, три раза. И радоваться!